# Django image field not showing on admin form for extended User model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

I am trying to extend the User model to allow a user to add an image to their profile, however have no option to save an image in the admin for my page. The other extended fields are showing. I am not sure why this is..

model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.TextField(default='', blank='')
    last_name = models.TextField(default='', blank='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


def user_image_upload_handler(instance, filename):
    fpath = pathlib.Path(filename)
    new_fname = str(uuid.uuid1())  # uuid1 -> uuid + timestamps
    return f"request/{new_fname}{fpath.suffix}"


class ProfilePicture(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_image_upload_handler, blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile, ProfilePicture


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = [Profile]
    list_display = ['id']


class ProfilePictureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = [ProfilePicture]
    extra = 10


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ProfileAdmin
    model = ProfilePictureAdmin


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/
first_name, last_name and email are already part of the standard django User so there was no need to extend those. My accounts/admin.py was simply

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import ProfilePicture

class ProfilePictureAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProfilePicture
    extra = 1


class ExtendedUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfilePictureAdmin]
    list_display = ['id', 'username', 'first_name']


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, ExtendedUserAdmin)
```